# How to prevent fullscreen form covering the taskbar?

Tags: c#, winforms, border, fullscreen, taskbar

Does anyone know how I can prevent my C# winform covering/going on top of the taskbar? My form's border style has been set to "FixedToolWindow" which seems to cause this. I thought about reducing the height of the form, when the user makes the form maximized, but that wouldn't work as people may have different size taskbars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class will give you both screen bounds and working area. The working area is the bounds minus the taskbar, so just set your form to be the same location as the Screen's [WorkingArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=VS.100).aspx)

> The working area is the desktop area
>   of the display, excluding taskbars,
>   docked windows, and docked tool bars.